# Extending homeomorphisms in Cantor set

Tags: general-topology

Let $C'$ be the "endpoints" of the Cantor set $C$. These are the endpoints of the missing intervals, and we know $C'\simeq \mathbb Q$.

Does every homeomorphism $h:C'\to C'$ extend to a homeomorphism of $C$?

What if I do $\langle b_0,b_1,...,b_n,z,z,z, ...\rangle\leftrightarrow \langle b_0,b_1,...,1-b_n,z,z,z ...\rangle$? In other words, looking at $C'$ as the eventually constant sequences in $2^\omega$, and flipping the value of a sequence at last place before it stays constant? That should produce a homeomorphism, but I wonder if it extends...

Comment: Every continuous map $C\to C$ is uniformly continuous. Is every homeomorphism $C' \to C'$ uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are easy examples of  homeomorphisms that cannot be extended to $C$.
For instance, take $p \in (C\setminus C') \cap (0, \frac12)$ and define 
$$h(x) = \cases{ 1 - x & if $p < x < 1-p$ \\ x & otherwise.}
$$
This is a continuous function on $C'$ because $C' \cap (p, 1-p)$ is clopen in $C'$. It also is its own inverse, so it is a homeomorphism.

Since $p$ is not a boundary point of a deleted interval, it is a limit point of both $C' \cap (0, p)$ and $C' \cap (p, 1-p)$. Therefore the oscillation of $h$ at $p$ is $1-2p$, which is positive.
It follows that $h$ cannot be
 extended to a continuous function on $C$.

Comment: very interesting.  I guess I should check the details in the other answers to find their flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed map isn't a homeomorphism, if I understand it correctly - consider the collection of sequences $a_0, a_1, a_2, \cdots$, where $a_i$ is the sequence consisting of $i$ ones followed by constant zeroes. This sequence of sequences has limit $\langle 1, 1, 1, \ldots\rangle$. Your map fixes the sequence, taking $a_i$ to $a_{i - 1}$ - but it takes the limit to $\langle 0, 1, 1, \ldots\rangle$. So this map isn't continuous, let alone a homeomorphism.

Side note: There *are* related homeomorphisms of $C'$, which do extend to homeomorphisms of $C$. Let $f_n$ be the map which simply flips the $n$th bit of the input. Each $f_n$ is now a homeomorphism (of either $C'$ or $C$, whichever you care more about).

As to whether every homeomorphism of $C'$ extends to a homeomorphism of $C$: yes, because every "irrational" point $r$ in $C$ is a limit of "rational" points $q_n$ from $C'$. Let $h$ be a homeomorphism from $C'$ to $C'$; it takes every clopen subset of $C'$ to a clopen subset of $C'$. The images of the intervals around each $q_n$ that encompass $r$ form a descending sequence of clopen sets around the $h(q_n)$. Since $C$ is compact, there is a (unique) element of $C$ that lies in the closures of all of these sets in $C$ - this can be taken to be $h(r)$. The resulting extension of $h$ can be easily seen to be a homeomorphism.

Comment: so you proved *every* dense subset of $C$ is homeomorphism-extendable?

Comment: @ForeverMozart Exactly.

Comment: and more generally, every dense subset of a compact zero-dimensional space is homeomorphism-extendable... I wonder why I never encountered this before?

Comment: The intersection of a decreasing sequence of closed sets in a compact space is nonempty, but it is not generally a singleton. That means your extension may not be well-defined. Even in cases where it is, there is no reason to believe it is injective.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen In the Cantor set, we can always choose the leftmost candidate. And it's injective because the homeomorphism must preserve whether two sequences limit to the same point.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of problems have been well-studied: see [this paper's introduction](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1982-084-01/S0002-9939-1982-0633296-0/S0002-9939-1982-0633296-0.pdf).

The Cantor set is Polish and zero-dimensional and homogeneous. 
This implies it is SLH (strongly locally homogeneous): there is a base of sets $U$ such that for all $x,y \in U$ there is a homeomorphism $f$ of $X$ such that $f(x)=y$ and $f(z) = z$ for all $z \in X\setminus U$.

Another theorem is that LCH Polish spaces are countable dense homogeneous: if $D$ and $E$ are countable dense in $X$ then there is an homeomorphism $h$ of $X$ such that $h[D] = E$. This is not the same as extending a homeomorphism of the dense subsets though. But I think the SLH property combined with the inductive convergence criterion allow you to do this for SLH Polish spaces, including the Cantor set.